# Stream Flush did not work, writing MemoryStream to two destinations

Tags: c#, stream

Trying to write some data from a MemoryStream to two destinations. First I write an Xml object to the memory stream, then write from the memory stream to a Mail Attachment and a Zip object. Only the second destination gets the data, despite doing Flush and Rewind between every step. How do I fix this?

Here is my source:

```
using (Stream XmlPartStream = new MemoryStream())
using (XmlTextWriter XmlPartWriter = new XmlTextWriter(XmlPartStream, Encoding.Unicode))
{
    XDocument TheXInvoice = TheInvoice.XInvoice(dtInvoiceLines);
    XmlPartWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;//xml output will be pretty-printed
    TheXInvoice.WriteTo(XmlPartWriter);//write to the MemoryStream
    XmlPartWriter.Flush();//finish writing to MemoryStream

    XmlPartStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);//rewind stream (Position=0 would also work)
    Attachment XmlPart = new Attachment(XmlPartStream, InvoiceXmlName, "application/xml");
    TheMail.Attachments.Add(XmlPart);
    XmlPartStream.Flush();//finish writing from MemoryStream to Attachment
    // BUG: no bytes in the Attachment

    XmlPartStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);//rewind stream (Position=0 would also work)
    byte[] ZippedXml = LempelZiv.GZip(XmlPartStream);
    // OK: Entire XML in the ZippedXml
```

---

Update:

Thanks to commenter rinukkusu, I tried to first mail, then zip. Now it works all OK. Apparently, the Mail lacks a Flush feature, and it delays actually reading its bytes...

Comment: Possibly the stream in the attachment will not be read until you actually send the mail, so the cursor is at the end again after zipping.

Comment: This is a crazy thing but it's worked for me before.  Try adding System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500) before or after Flush.  I can't remember the details but I used this before and it was like the system needed a moment to catch up.  Of course, it is more likely that @rinukkusu is right :)

Comment: I faced the same issue, had to create a new memory stream

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4266487/1845672 I have to `CopyTo` a second MemoryStream, but that gave me a second stream with no data.

Comment: @rinukkusu That may indeed be the case. I will try to first zip, then mail.

Answer (score -1):

Try invoking `XmlPartWriter.Close()` after the first `Flush`.

Comment: This will also close the underlying stream, so it can't be read after this. How would that help?

Comment: This might indeed force Mail to hurry up reading the data, but as the downvoters pointed out, will also prevent ever reading from that stream again, forcing me to do the zip reading before the mail reading. Thanks for your effort.