# how to keep a reference to the stream when I select the image from the mediaPicker , then use that reference again when creating the FormFile?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to store a model informations in my Data Base, this informations contain an image, so I created a simple view with some entrys, with a media picker button to pick it and an image witch display the picked one.
This is the button method and the store method:

```cs
 async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Please pick a photo"
            });

            if (result != null)
            {
                var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

                resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }
        }
  public async Task SaveMachine()

        {

            var machine = new Machine
            {
                Machine_Name = nom.Text,
                Machine_Qr = qr.Text,
                Files = resultImage

            };

            await _rest.AddMachine(machine);

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
```

But I can't create **Files = resultImage** because the Files in the model is in IFormFile. So can anyone give me an idea how to keep a reference to the stream when I select the image, then use that reference again when creating the FormFile?

Comment: you keep a reference to the stream the same way you do to any C# object.  Create a variable that references the object.  Instead of `var stream` which will go out of scope immediately when the method exits, create a **class level variable** that will remain in scope.

Comment: Set position to 0 and use it again, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266448/reading-stream-twice